# how to restore data values that already converted into scientific notation in a table

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

so i have a problem where i inserted some values into my table that the value automatically converted into a scientific notation (ex: 8.24e+04) does anyone know how restore the original value or how keep the original values in the table?

i'm using double precision as data type for the column and i just noticed that double precision data type often convert long number values into scientific notation.

this is how table looks like after i inserted some values

```
test=# select * from demo;
| string_col |        values         |
|------------|-----------------------|
| Rocket     |          123228435521 |
| Test       |        13328422942213 |
| Power      | 1.243343991231232e+15 |
| Pull       | 1.233433459353712e+15 |
| Drag       |         1244375399128 |

edb=# \d+ demo;
                                             Table "public.demo"
   Column   |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 string_col | character varying(20) |           |          |         | extended |              |
 values     | double precision      |           |          |         | plain    |              |
Access method: heap
```

this just some dummy table i used to explain my question here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to format the number using `to_char` if you want it in a specific format:

```
SELECT 31672516735473059594023526::double precision,
       to_char(
          31672516735473059594023526::double precision,
          '999999999999999999999999999.99999999999999FM'
       );

        float8         │          to_char           
═══════════════════════╪════════════════════════════
 3.167251673547306e+25 │ 31672516735473058997862400
(1 row)
```

The result is not exact because the precision of `double precision` is not high enough.

If you don't want the rounding errors and want to avoid scientific notation as well, use the data type `numeric` instead.